# Windows 7 backup and restore: Is each backup incremental or complete?

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, windows-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does built in Windows 7 backup perform differential (incremental) backups?](https://superuser.com/questions/60554/does-built-in-windows-7-backup-perform-differential-incremental-backups)

I have a computer that's been taking backups using Windows 7's Backup and Restore feature.  However, I now need to reclaim hard disk space, and am trying to figure out what I can safely delete.

When I go into the Backup and Restore options on the machine, it shows several backups.  Is it safe to delete the older ones?  Or is it an incremental backup, that means that files not changed since before the last backup would then be lost?