# Windows 7 backup

Tags: windows-7, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does built in Windows 7 backup perform differential (incremental) backups?](https://superuser.com/questions/60554/does-built-in-windows-7-backup-perform-differential-incremental-backups)

Hi,

I use Windows 7 Backup for simple home backup. Windows 7 backup seems to maintain about 3 versions of the backup, for the last three days. I only ever want the lastest set of files to be backed up - is that an incremental? I basically only want it to backup those files that have changed.

I know that its better practice to have multiple versions of the backup, however I swap out external hard drives every couple of days, so I do always have a couple of versions.

Thanks Al

Comment: Your question is effectively answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/60554/does-built-in-windows-7-backup-perform-differential-incremental-backups.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth reading about backups. This article from Acronis provides information about Full, Differential and Incremental Backups.
http://www.acronis.com/resource/solutions/backup/2005/incremental-backups.html

It sounds like you want to be doing differential backups. One full backup and then differentials every so often only storing the latest one.

Comment: What Acronis products offer and what Windows 7 offer are completely different. You get the choice with Acronis, but you don't with Windows 7 - for further details, see the link in my comment to the OP.

Comment: The article was meant only to allow the user to understand the difference between differential and incremental backups. But the answer to the other question is quite interesting.