# Windows 7 backup

Tags: windows-7, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 backup](https://superuser.com/questions/209310/windows-7-backup)

Hi,

I use Windows 7 Backup for simple home backup. Windows 7 backup seems to maintain about 3 versions of the backup, for the last three days. I only ever want the lastest set of files to be backed up - is that an incremental? I basically only want it to backup those files that have changed.

I know that its better practice to have multiple versions of the backup, however I swap out external hard drives every couple of days, so I do always have a couple of versions.

Thanks
Al

Comment: So are you trying to do this in C# or C++?

Comment: try superuser.com for this question

Comment: This doesn't belong here, go to "Super user" with this question

Comment: Sorry guys - didnt realise this didnt belong here - although "stack" should have given the game away!