# windows 7 backup

Tags: windows-7, backup, data-recovery

Does the windows 7 backup system version the files? Or does it just backup and erase the old set of files?

Can I set it to backup every hour? Does it only backup the changes in files, or erase them all and save them again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the windows 7 backup system
>   version the files?

Yes, if system protection is turned on.

> Or does it just backup and erase the
>   old set of files?

Not sure exactly what you mean here.

> Can I set it to backup every hour?

Yes.

> Does it only backup the changes in
>   files, or erase them all and save them
>   again?

Only the files you change are updated, backups of the other files already exist from the previous restore point.

**I think all of these questions are answered in more detail [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions).**

Answer (score 0):

It does do incremental backups, so there may be multiple copies of a single file. When a something is changed, the entire file is saved again in the next backup.

Comment: thanks Tom, it only updates/backs up the files that are changed correct?

Answer (score 0):

this article should help answer your question: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsbackup/thread/c200e540-b36d-40c8-9957-690d447dbef9

Also: (Answer provided by A Dwarf (6,504) From this question [Does built in Windows 7 backup perform differential (incremental) backups?](https://superuser.com/questions/60554/does-built-in-windows-7-backup-perform-differential-incremental-backups))
**Windows 7 Backup is a block based file backup.**

This means each block in a file is examined and if a duplicate already exists on the last backup, and this is the important bit, even if from a different file, that block is not saved. Quite good :)

The first backup is always a full backup. The following backups will only save changed blocks. Disadvantage is you cannot manage your backups individually