# How do I clean Windows 7 backup catalog

Tags: windows-7, backup

I've got WindowsImageBackup catalog which takes up 900GB on my hard drive, of which System Image takes 823 GB. This becomes a problem as it takes nearly half of my data drive.

I'm using "Keep only the latest system image and minimize space" in the system image settings.

System drive size is 255Gb (155 filled and 100 free).

What can I do to decrease the System Image size?

Here's the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  If your system drive is only 250GB then its not possible to have a catalog that takes up 900GB.  There are tons of questions about the WindowsImageBackup catalog on this site might want to read some of the better ones.

Comment: It is. the backup is on a drive that is 2TB large. I call it data drive

Comment: I remember a discussion on this very issue on Security Now! and it was discussed that the space taken by the WindowsImageBackup Catalog is often not reported the correct way if you simply do a properties on the folder. I would download a program ( there are many ) that will report each and every file and the size it takes up. I would bet there are some large files taking up the space.  I have day 1 Windows 7 installation, all updates, has never had to be reinstalled and my WindowsImageBackup catalog is not that large.  There is something else going on.

Comment: @Moab, do you know if the Windows backup can do differentials instead of incrementals?

Comment: @RandolphWest don't know for sure, its a very limited image backup software so I doubt it, no real way to configure it either. I used it for a while but found it had too many limitations for me.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use it because Acronis does a great job for me. I was just curious. Thanks.

Comment: @RandolphWest see this  http://superuser.com/questions/60554/does-built-in-windows-7-backup-perform-differential-incremental-backups

Comment: @Ramhound I came upon this problem after analyzing the drive with WinDirStat. The file size reported is genuine

Answer (score 0):

#### The command-line `wbadmin` tool can be used to delete the backup catalog.

- In an elevated command prompt, run the following command:

  ```
  wbadmin delete catalog
  ```
- `wbadmin` is the command-line Windows Backup tool. This command deletes the backup catalog, removing all record of prior file and system image backups on the machine. You will need to create a new set of backups after running this command. (File History on Windows 8 and later is unaffected.)

More information is available on [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742154.aspx).